# Suspend from KDE 5 (Plasma) lockscreen?

Tags: kubuntu, suspend, kde, lock-screen, kde5

How to make it possible to suspend computer from KDE 5 (Plasma) lockscreen ?

Comment: P.S. I am asking it because closing lid is out of possibile solutions, it is infeasible in my case.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/69vase/suspend_button_disabled_on_lock_screen/dh9uei8/) from martin (a kde dev), this is currently not possible. However, there does seem to exist a global shortcut whitelist!

BTW, closing the lid on the lockscreen does suspend the system in my case!